# GameBoy compiler with system registers and interrupts

Tags: c, compiler-construction, z80, gameboy

I have been spending a lot of time learning GameBoy programming, as I was already familiar with Z80 Assembly I wasn't afraid of jumping into using it. I would (of course) find it much more productive to program in C or C++ however cannot find a full compiler for the GameBoy, the compilers I can find manage everything themselves and do not give access to system registers to the programmer and also have some horrible drawbacks such as 100% CPU utilization and no interrupt support.
Would it be possible to address system registers much like Arduino's AVR compiler? being able to address a CPU or system register simply with its name such as `DDRD = %10101011`
What would I have to do to add interrupts and system registers into a compiler? All but one system register are only one byte memory addresses and interrupts vectors are of course memory locations, the only one system register that isn't a memory address can only be modified with two Assembly instructions `EI` and `DI` but that could be inline functions correct?

Comment: [GBDK](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/) is a C compiler that does let you directly interact with registers - use `gb/hardware.h`.  However, the documentation provided isn't good, so you can't actually see what the names are in the doc.  Just open up the file under `include/gb/hardware.h` and you can see everything.  It also has interrupt support - see `add_VBL`, `add_LCD`, `add_TIM`, `add_SIO`, and `add_JOY` in [`gb/gb.h`](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/doc/html/gb.h.html).

Comment: Wow thanks @Pokechu22. Sorry you didn't answer in time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual tactic is to create your own pointers to system registers.  I don't know the address of DDRD, but something like this should to the trick:

```
volatile unsigned char *reg_DDRD = (unsigned char *)0xE000;
*reg_DDRD = 0xAB;
```

Most C compilers don't support binary constants but you can use them with some macro hackery.  And you can use macros to make slightly more intuitive syntax:

```
#define DDRD (*reg_DDRD)
DDRD = 0xAB;
```

There's no sense in modifying the compiler when vanilla C code can work just as well.

Handling interrupts comes down to solving 3 problems.  The first is to have the interrupt vector address do a jump to a C function.  As that is in ROM you'll need to modify the C runtime environment to initialize that.  This gets pretty system dependent, but usually what you'll want to do is add an assembly language file that looks like this:

```
     org 38h   ; or wherever the gameboy CPU jumps to on interrupt
 jp _intr_function
```

This should cause the CPU to go to `intr_function()` in your C program.  You may or may not need the leading underscore.  And you may not be able to set the destination address in the assembler file with `org` but instead have to fool around with the linker and sections.

The second problem is that the C function won't necessarily save all the registers it should.  You can do this by adding in-line assembly to it, along these lines:

```
void intr_function()
{
     asm(" push af");
     asm(" push bc");
     asm(" push de");
     asm(" push hl");

     // ... now do what you like here.

     asm(" pop hl");
     asm(" pop de");
     asm(" pop bc");
     asm(" pop af");
 }
```

Finally, the interrupt may have to be acknowledged by manipulating a hardware register.  But you can do that in the C code so nothing special about that.

I'm not clear about the issue with wait loops.  Standard C compilers don't have such a feature built in.  They call main() and if you want to loop it is up to you.  It is true that the C-like language used in the Arduino SDK has its own built-in infinite loop that calls the functions you write, but that's not normal C.

Comment: This is in-fact how all of those vendor-provided header files do it for you anyway.  I'm not intimately familiar with Z80 internals, but do be aware of architectures where a pointer isn't necessarily just any pointer. Bank-switching and separate address spaces which can only be accessed via special instructions are out there which make C's view of a flat memory address space invalid.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The GameBoy does use bank switching, but luckily just for 16K of ROM only so system registers never move.

Comment: @LeeAllan Thanks for clarifying. I didn't expect that they would - that would make a system quite difficult to interact with.

Comment: Any tricks or tips on removing the 100% CPU load (wait loop)? Any idea on how to add interrupts vectors? The GB has a few fixed location vectors so surely its just a matter of adding a jump to my function there..

Answer (score 3):

First off, you can use [GBDK](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/), which is a C compiler and library for the Gameboy.  It does provide access to the registers in `gb/hardware.h` (but that isn't listed in the doc file, since there's no comment for each individual register).  It also supplies access to interrupts via methods in  `gb/gb.h`: `add_VBL`, `add_LCD`, `add_TIM`, `add_SIO`, and `add_JOY`.  (There's also remove methods named `remove_`).

For reference and/or your own use, here's the contents of `gb/hardware.h`:

```c
#define __REG   volatile UINT8 *

#define P1_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF00)    /* Joystick: 1.1.P15.P14.P13.P12.P11.P10 */
#define SB_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF01)    /* Serial IO data buffer */
#define SC_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF02)    /* Serial IO control register */
#define DIV_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF04)    /* Divider register */
#define TIMA_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF05)    /* Timer counter */
#define TMA_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF06)    /* Timer modulo */
#define TAC_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF07)    /* Timer control */
#define IF_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF0F)    /* Interrupt flags: 0.0.0.JOY.SIO.TIM.LCD.VBL */
#define NR10_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF10)    /* Sound register */
#define NR11_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF11)    /* Sound register */
#define NR12_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF12)    /* Sound register */
#define NR13_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF13)    /* Sound register */
#define NR14_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF14)    /* Sound register */
#define NR21_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF16)    /* Sound register */
#define NR22_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF17)    /* Sound register */
#define NR23_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF18)    /* Sound register */
#define NR24_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF19)    /* Sound register */
#define NR30_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF1A)    /* Sound register */
#define NR31_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF1B)    /* Sound register */
#define NR32_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF1C)    /* Sound register */
#define NR33_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF1D)    /* Sound register */
#define NR34_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF1E)    /* Sound register */
#define NR41_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF20)    /* Sound register */
#define NR42_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF21)    /* Sound register */
#define NR43_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF22)    /* Sound register */
#define NR44_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF23)    /* Sound register */
#define NR50_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF24)    /* Sound register */
#define NR51_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF25)    /* Sound register */
#define NR52_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF26)    /* Sound register */
#define LCDC_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF40)    /* LCD control */
#define STAT_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF41)    /* LCD status */
#define SCY_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF42)    /* Scroll Y */
#define SCX_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF43)    /* Scroll X */
#define LY_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF44)    /* LCDC Y-coordinate */
#define LYC_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF45)    /* LY compare */
#define DMA_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF46)    /* DMA transfer */
#define BGP_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF47)    /* BG palette data */
#define OBP0_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF48)    /* OBJ palette 0 data */
#define OBP1_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF49)    /* OBJ palette 1 data */
#define WY_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF4A)    /* Window Y coordinate */
#define WX_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF4B)    /* Window X coordinate */
#define KEY1_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF4D)    /* CPU speed */
#define VBK_REG     (*(__REG)0xFF4F)    /* VRAM bank */
#define HDMA1_REG   (*(__REG)0xFF51)    /* DMA control 1 */
#define HDMA2_REG   (*(__REG)0xFF52)    /* DMA control 2 */
#define HDMA3_REG   (*(__REG)0xFF53)    /* DMA control 3 */
#define HDMA4_REG   (*(__REG)0xFF54)    /* DMA control 4 */
#define HDMA5_REG   (*(__REG)0xFF55)    /* DMA control 5 */
#define RP_REG      (*(__REG)0xFF56)    /* IR port */
#define BCPS_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF68)    /* BG color palette specification */
#define BCPD_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF69)    /* BG color palette data */
#define OCPS_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF6A)    /* OBJ color palette specification */
#define OCPD_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF6B)    /* OBJ color palette data */
#define SVBK_REG    (*(__REG)0xFF70)    /* WRAM bank */
#define IE_REG      (*(__REG)0xFFFF)    /* Interrupt enable */
```

These are done in the same way as [George Phillips's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035985/3991344), and thus can be used like normal variables.

The code that is used by GBDK to add and remove interrupts is found in `libc\gb\crt0.s`, but I don't know enough of assembly to include the relevant sections in this post.

I'm not sure about how to avoid the busy loop either.